# Node/React client proxy not working, componentDidMount() not fetching data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

EDIT: Link to project repo can be found [here](https://github.com/pedrorolando/recipe-app).

I am trying to fetch data when my profile page loads in my React app.
I have the client running on my localhost:3000 and the server on localhost:5000.

I also have a proxy in the package.json of my client folder that points it to localhost:5000 (supposedly).
In my server file I also have cors, and all the usual bells and whistles I have used in the past.

Whenever my component mounts, in my console I get a 404 error saying my GET request failed, and it says it attempted to reach localhost:3000/recipes - according to my proxy, this is wrong as it should be making the request to localhost:5000.

However, it gets even trickier because, to test it, I changed and hardcoded my route to be localhost:5000 but even that returned a 404 error.

At first I figured it was something wrong with my backend GET request logic, but the thing is, when I stick the same function that makes the get request inside componentDidUpdate(), it successfully fetches all the recipes (it is a recipes app), only it fires an infinite loop and goes crazy, and obviously I can't have that.

Anyone know what is going on here? Why does my getRecipes() function (that makes the get request) not working inside componentDidMount(), getting a 404 error, not successfully proxying, but then works inside componentDidUpdate()? Why the infinite loop?

Here is my frontend code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input
} from "reactstrap";
import styles from "./RecipeList.module.css";
// import { addRecipe } from "../RecipeFunctions/RecipeFunctions";
import axios from "axios";
import RecipeItem from "../RecipeItem/RecipeItem";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

export default class RecipeList extends Component {
  state = {
    recipes: [],
    modal: false,
    email: "",
    recipeName: "",
    ingredients: "",
    directions: "",
    errors: {
      msg: ""
    }
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newRecipe = {
      user_email: this.state.email,
      title: this.state.recipeName,
      ingredients: this.state.ingredients,
      directions: this.state.directions
    };

    // Make Post Request w/ Axios from RecipeFunctions.js
    this.addRecipe(newRecipe);
    this.getRecipes();
  };

  getRecipes = () => {
    axios.get(`/recipes/${this.state.email}`).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        recipes: res.data
      });
    });
  };

  addRecipe = newRecipe => {
    axios.post("/recipes", newRecipe).then(response => {
      console.log("Recipe added.");
      console.log(this.state.email)
    });
  };

  deleteRecipe = id => {
    axios
      .delete(`/recipes/${id}`)
      .then(this.getRecipes())
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  viewRecipe = id => {
    axios
      .post(`/viewrecipe/${id}`)
      .then(this.getRecipes())
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  closeRecipe = id => {
    axios
      .post(`/closerecipe/${id}`)
      .then(this.getRecipes())
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const token = localStorage.usertoken;
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      this.setState({
        firstname: decoded.firstname,
        lastname: decoded.lastname,
        email: decoded.email
      });
    } catch {
      this.setState({
        errors: {
          msg: "You must be logged in to see your profile."
        }
      });
    }
    this.getRecipes();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.email) {
      return (
        <div id={styles.compWrapper} className="container">
          <div>
            <div id={styles.titleWrapper} className="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
              <h1 className="text-center">{this.state.firstname}'s Cookbook</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="text-center">
              <div>
                <Button
                  id={styles.addRecipeBtn}
                  outline
                  color="secondary"
                  onClick={this.toggle}
                  size="sm"
                >
                  Add Recipe
                </Button>
                <div className={styles.feedWrapper}>
                  <Modal
                    className={styles.addRecipeModal}
                    isOpen={this.state.modal}
                    toggle={this.toggle}
                  >
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>New Recipe</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup>
                          <Label for="item">Recipe Name</Label>
                          <Input
                            type="text"
                            name="recipeName" // *must match this.state above
                            id="item"
                            placeholder="ex. Chicken Pot Pie"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                          />
                          <Label className={styles.inputLabel} for="item">
                            Ingredients
                          </Label>
                          <Input
                            type="textarea"
                            size="lg"
                            name="ingredients" // *must match this.state above
                            id={styles.ingredientsTextArea}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                          />
                          <Label className={styles.inputLabel} for="item">
                            Directions
                          </Label>
                          <Input
                            type="textarea"
                            size="lg"
                            name="directions" // *must match this.state above
                            id={styles.directionsTextArea}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                          />
                          <Button
                            color="dark"
                            style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}
                            block
                            onClick={this.toggle}
                          >
                            Add
                          </Button>
                        </FormGroup>
                      </Form>
                    </ModalBody>
                  </Modal>
                </div>
                <div
                  id={styles.recipeListWrapper}
                  className="recipe-list-container"
                >
                  {this.state.recipes.map(recipe => (
                    <RecipeItem
                      id={recipe._id}
                      title={recipe.title}
                      ingredients={recipe.ingredients}
                      directions={recipe.directions}
                      beingViewed={recipe.beingViewed}
                      viewRecipe={this.viewRecipe}
                      closeRecipe={this.closeRecipe}
                      deleteRecipe={this.deleteRecipe}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <p className="text-center jumbotron mt-5">{this.state.errors.msg}</p>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);

dotenv.config();
const db = process.env.DB_CONNECT;

const Users = require("./routes/Users");
const Recipes = require("./routes/Recipes");

app.use("/users", Users);
app.use("/recipes", Recipes);

mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
  .catch(() => console.log(err));

app.post("/viewrecipe/:id", (req, res) => {
  Recipe.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: { beingViewed: true } })
    .then(res.send("Recipe being viewed."))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

app.post("/closerecipe/:id", (req, res) => {
  Recipe.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: { beingViewed: false } })
    .then(res.send("Recipe closed."))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

app.get("/showrecipes", (req, res) => {
  Recipe.find({}).then(recipes => res.send(recipes));
});

app.delete("/deleterecipes", (req, res) => {
  Recipe.deleteMany({}).then(res.send("All recipes deleted. Database empty."));
});

// Serve static assets if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

If necessary, here is the actual route (the "recipes." is express router with a base of /recipes):

```
recipes.get("/:useremail", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.params.useremail) {
    res.send("You must be logged in to access recipes.");
  }
  Recipe.find({
    user_email: req.params.useremail
  })
    .then(recipes => {
        res.send(recipes)
    .catch(err => {
      res.send("error: " + err);
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where do you have your code? push your code in your git hub and share the link.

Comment: @Arjun just did, link is at the top.

Comment: try replacing axios.get("/recipes") to axios.get("https://localhost:5000/recipes)

Comment: @Arjun Not sure where you are looking but client does have react-scripts in package.json. And just added localhost:5000 to get request, and now I'm getting: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: whats the full error message? Is it cors issue ?

Comment: I don't have credentials so I can't login to your system and check whats going on

Answer (score 0):

in your fetch request, try to use 192.168.17.161:5000 instead of localhost:5000

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: when you write localhost, that will call your localhost machine, where the browser is present, you can create a subdomain of your localhost and use it, or you can use, the adress where your application is hosted you can check it by using ipconfig, if it's not by default 192.168.17.161

Comment: Ok will try it and see if it helps with troubleshooting